SectionList jumps/glitches when paginated list gets appended at the bottom
The response of my paginated code looks something like -
Page 1
0: {title: '2024-07-11', data: Array(3)}
1: {title: '2024-07-12', data: Array(1)}
2: {title: '2024-07-15', data: Array(2)}
3: {title: '2024-07-16', data: Array(1)}
4: {title: '2024-07-17', data: Array(1)}
5: {title: '2024-07-19', data: Array(3)}
6: {title: '2024-07-20', data: Array(2)}
7: {title: '2024-07-22', data: Array(2)}
8: {title: '2024-07-23', data: Array(4)}
9: {title: '2024-07-24', data: Array(1)}
length: 10

Page 2
0: {title: '2024-07-11', data: Array(3)}
1: {title: '2024-07-12', data: Array(1)}
2: {title: '2024-07-15', data: Array(2)}
3: {title: '2024-07-16', data: Array(1)}
4: {title: '2024-07-17', data: Array(1)}
5: {title: '2024-07-19', data: Array(3)}
6: {title: '2024-07-20', data: Array(2)}
7: {title: '2024-07-22', data: Array(2)}
8: {title: '2024-07-23', data: Array(4)}
9: {title: '2024-07-24', data: Array(1)}
10: {title: '2024-07-24', data: Array(3)}
11: {title: '2024-07-11', data: Array(3)}
12: {title: '2024-07-12', data: Array(1)}
13: {title: '2024-07-15', data: Array(2)}
14: {title: '2024-07-16', data: Array(2)}
15: {title: '2024-07-18', data: Array(2)}
16: {title: '2024-07-19', data: Array(3)}
17: {title: '2024-07-22', data: Array(2)}
18: {title: '2024-07-23', data: Array(2)}
length: 19

Page 3
0: {title: '2024-07-11', data: Array(3)}
1: {title: '2024-07-12', data: Array(1)}
2: {title: '2024-07-15', data: Array(2)}
3: {title: '2024-07-16', data: Array(1)}
4: {title: '2024-07-17', data: Array(1)}
5: {title: '2024-07-19', data: Array(3)}
6: {title: '2024-07-20', data: Array(2)}
7: {title: '2024-07-22', data: Array(2)}
8: {title: '2024-07-23', data: Array(4)}
9: {title: '2024-07-24', data: Array(1)}
10: {title: '2024-07-24', data: Array(3)}
11: {title: '2024-07-11', data: Array(3)}
12: {title: '2024-07-12', data: Array(1)}
13: {title: '2024-07-15', data: Array(2)}
14: {title: '2024-07-16', data: Array(2)}
15: {title: '2024-07-18', data: Array(2)}
16: {title: '2024-07-19', data: Array(3)}
17: {title: '2024-07-22', data: Array(2)}
18: {title: '2024-07-23', data: Array(2)}
19: {title: '2024-07-24', data: Array(1)}
20: {title: '2024-07-25', data: Array(5)}
21: {title: '2024-07-11', data: Array(2)}
22: {title: '2024-07-12', data: Array(4)}
23: {title: '2024-07-15', data: Array(1)}
24: {title: '2024-07-17', data: Array(2)}
25: {title: '2024-07-18', data: Array(1)}
26: {title: '2024-07-20', data: Array(1)}
27: {title: '2024-07-22', data: Array(1)}
length: 28

I am using react-query's useInifiniteQuery and page values are flattened.
When the third and the final page is fetched and rendered, I see the following glitch -

import format from 'date-fns/format';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { RefreshControl, SectionList, View } from 'react-native';

import { BookableAppointment } from '@app-types/appointments';
import {
  AppointmentCard,
  AppointmentListLoader,
} from '@components/app-specific';
import { CircularLoader, Typography } from '@components/core';
import { createUseStyle } from '@theme';

import { useGetAppointmentBooking } from '../../hooks/get-appointment-booking';

export const useBookableAppointmentsStyle = createUseStyle(t => ({
  listEmptyContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  header: {
    backgroundColor: t.palette.background.main,
  },

  contentContainer: {
    gap: 16,
    paddingVertical: t.moderateVerticalScale(10, 1),
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export const BookableAppointments = () => {
  const styles = useBookableAppointmentsStyle();

  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    loadMore,
    isRefetching,
    refetch,
  } = useGetAppointmentBooking();

  const renderBookableAppointment = useCallback(
    ({ item }: { item: BookableAppointment }) => {
      return (
        <AppointmentCard
          key={item.EndDateTime.toString()}
          appointment={{
            EndDateTime: item.EndDateTime,
            Id: item.Id,
            LocationName: item.LocationName,
            StartDateTime: item.StartDateTime,
          }}
        />
      );
    },
    [],
  );

  const onPullToRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
    await refetch();
  }, [refetch]);

  if (isLoading && !data.length) {
    return <AppointmentListLoader />;
  }

  const ListEmptyComponent = !isLoading ? (
    <View style={styles.listEmptyContainer}>
      <Typography variant="body1" color="description" align="center">
        Unfortunately, there are no available appointments for the selected date
        range.
      </Typography>
    </View>
  ) : null;

  const renderSectionHeader = ({
    section: { title },
  }: {
    section: { title: string };
  }) => (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Typography variant="h4" weight="bold">
        {format(new Date(title), 'EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy')}
      </Typography>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <SectionList
      keyExtractor={item => item.EndDateTime.toString()}
      sections={data}
      renderItem={renderBookableAppointment}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={isRefetching} onRefresh={onPullToRefresh} />
      }
      onEndReached={loadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      ListFooterComponent={
        isFetchingNextPage && data.length ? <CircularLoader /> : null
      }
      ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
      renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    />
  );
};


I have tried adding initialNumToRender, maxToRenderPerBatch, etc for additional performance gains but things became worse.
I am not sure why things render perfectly on the 2nd page but I see this glitch when the 3rd page renders

Hi I also currently struggle with this issue.
There is a similar issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36414 and it seems to come from sectionList itself and its virtualization and it occurs in the new react-native versions.
By default sectionList is loading 21 items in advance that are not yet in the view. You can adjust this value with windowSize. When you crank that value up the issue will not occur till the list is even bigger and you scroll even further.
Also it seems to occur mostly when you have stickySectionHeadersEnabled true. Which is default on iOS. So the issue seems to be that the SectionList virtualization combined with sticky headers leads to problems. disableVirtualization will completely erase the bug but then you can render an endless list which could cause other problems.
Possible Solutions are:

use other third party lists (FlashList, Recyclerlistview)
disable Sticky Headers (maybe build your own header component to make up for that)
disable virtualization or increase windowSize (could cause other problems)

I think I will look into other list components since I also run into other bugs and don't think I can create a bulletproof Feed with sectionList.
Good luck
Edit:
I switched to FlashList and it works like a charm.
https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/guides/section-list
I had to change my data structure to a flat array as in the tutorial. But it was not a lot of work and so far all the bugs I experienced with sectionList are taken care of and the performance is great.
